Saving custom connection list within VSCode
I have a set of connections that I have configured within VSCode each which have a custom name, color and icon. Some of them connect to Office 365 PowerShell, linux, etc.
What I would like to be able to do is save their state so when I next open the application they are there for me to use. I am not concerned about authenticating as I am happy to do this manually if I have to.
Is there a solution for this?
An example of my set up is attached to this post.
Connection layout
I have tried going to File -> Save Workspace As... option but this does not seem to work. If I reload this it does not restore my connection styles.

what kind of connections are these? SSH?
